# Remove whole string in wysiwyg (tinymce)

Tags: string, wordpress, tinymce

i have a function in my wordpress blog which adds citations like "(altmann, 2013)" which is referring to journal paper. Hidden (with :hidden) in that text are some metadata about that paper.

I need a function which disallow the user to click on that particular text block (so either the user cant click it or the curser jumps to the left or right and when a user tries to remove (hit remove or backspace) the whole text-block should be deleted (and not just the last bracket.

I tried a lot with onlicks (which do not work) and i am out of ideas. can anyone help me?